# Simplify the boolean equation

Tags: boolean-algebra

I am trying to simplify this boolean expression:

```
F = A B ((A + C')') + B (A C + A' B) + (A + B)(A' + C D)
```

The resultant solution is supposed to be:

```
F = A C D + ('A B) + B C
```

But all I can get is

```
F = A C D + ('A B) + A B C + B C D
```

Help would be appreciated.

Checked on [this page](http://tma.main.jp/logic/logic.php?lang=en&type=eq&eq=A%20B%20%28~%28A%20%2B%20~C%29%29%20%2B%20B%20%28A%20C%20%2B%20~A%20B%29%20%2B%20%28A%20%2B%20B%29%28~A%20%2B%20C%20D%29) and it says minified form is what real solution is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From where you ended up:

$ACD + A'B + ABC + BCD =$ (Idempotence)

$ACD + A'B + A'B + ABC + BCD =$ (Adjacency)

$ACD + A'B + (A'BC + A'BC') + ABC + BCD =$ (Association and Commutation)

$ACD + (A'B + A'BC') + A'BC + ABC + BCD =$ (Absorption)

$ACD + A'B + (A'BC + ABC) + BCD =$ (Adjacency)

$ACD + A'B + (BC + BCD) =$ (Absorption)

$ACD + A'B + BC$

Comment: How can one get this solution if the person doesn't know it in advance. For example step: (Association and Commutation) that is really confusing, why would I do it? Could you please care to explain.

Comment: @roko Excellent question!!  Yes, obviously I was greatly guided by knowing what I had to obtain.. But in general there are a few principles you can always be on the lookout for: absorption, adjacency, and reduction being the main ones. Once you get a lot of experience with these, you start to see how you can rewrite terms in such a way that you can combine and simplify them, even if sometimes you first need to temporarily expand some terms as I did in my solution.  And finally, the step where I did Association and Commutation was really just about reordering the terms, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

The supposed solution is correct.

Check the [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) as confirmation:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alex Kemper's answer is, I suppose, the *de facto* way to simplify the expression.
Another way to conclude that $$ABC+A'B+ACD+BCD = BC+A'B+ACD,$$ using Boolean Algebra axioms, is the following:
\begin{align}
A'B + ACD + BC
&= A'B +ACD + (A+A')BC\\
&= A'B + ACD + ABC + A'BC\\
&= (A'B + A'BC) + ACD + ABC\\
&= A'B + ACD + ABC. \tag{absorption}
\end{align}
Now, 
\begin{align}
ABC+A'B+ACD+BCD = A'B + ACD + ABC
&\Leftrightarrow BCD \leq A'B + ACD + ABC\\
&\Leftrightarrow BCD (A'B + ACD + ABC) = BCD.
\end{align}
But $$BCD (A'B + ACD + ABC) = (A'BCD) + (ABCD) + (ABCD) = (A + A') BCD = BCD.$$